# l3build can't find files included with \input in generated style files

Tags: l3build

In the following example, `l3build doc` fails with a complaint that it can't find file `test.def` which is included in `test.sty` using `\input{test.def}`.

I can build the documentation successfully manually (i.e., by running `latex test.ins`; `pdflatex test.dtx`; `pdflatex test.dtx`.

Any clue as to what I'm doing wrong? Or could this be a bug in `l3build`?

## MWE

Sorry for the three files. Not sure how to do it more neatly.

### build.lua

```
module = "test"
```

### test.ins

```
\input l3docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{\file{test.sty}{\from{test.dtx}{package}}
          \file{test.def}{\from{test.dtx}{definitions}}
}
\endbatchfile
```

### test.dtx

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*driver>
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{test}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \fillertext
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
\ProvidesPackage{test}
\input{test.def}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*definitions>
\ProvidesFile{test.def}
\def\fillertext{Filler text.}
%</definitions>
%    \end{macrocode}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By design, `l3build` unpacks files in one place, and copies *those requested* to a different place for running tests and typesetting. So you need to tell it which files to make available. Here, you probably want the `.def` files in `installfiles`

```
installfiles = {"*.def", "*.sty"}
```